# ¿como utilizar las rutas relativas en javaEE para .war en hosting?

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee, servlets

hola estoy intentando publicar mi proyecto en un hosting con tomcat, mi problema redice en la manipulación de archivos, ya que de manera local con rutas absolutas funciona perfectamente, pero en el hosting no por razones obvias, esperaba encontrara una solución fácil para organizarlo por rutas relativas y no ha sido así, por eso acudo a ustedes.

```
<%
String ruta = "ArchivosCh";
//String ruta ="C:\\Users\\GEORGE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ChMaquina\\web\\ArchivosCh"; funciona perfecto de forma local
File dir = new File(ruta);

String[] nombreArchivos = dir.list();//retorna y guarda la lista de los ficheros en el directorio
int i = 0;
for (String re : nombreArchivos) {//muestra los nombres de los archivos
}
%>
```

este es mi código para subir el archivo, como comentario esta la linea que funciona perfecto de forma local.

utilizo el servidor https://app.jelastic.saveincloud.net/

dejo el código completo del archivo aquí abajo:

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : index1
    Created on : 28/05/2019, 12:57:33 AM
    Author     : GEORGE
--%>

<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="clases.Memoria" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/img_default/index.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="css/bootstrap.css.map" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css">


        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/npm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Inicio de formulario direccion al servlet servChMaquina -->
        <!---->
        <form name="" method="post"  action="" target="" enctype="">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm col-lg-12 col-sm-10 col-xs-12" role="group" aria-label="">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <div class="list-group" role="group">
                        <label type="" class="control-label">Memoria</label>
                        <input type="number" class="input-sm" name="memoriaf" placeholder="Null" value="<%out.print(Memoria.getMemoria());%>"/>

                        <label title="" class="control-label">Kernel</label>
                        <input type="number" class="input-sm" name="kernelf" placeholder="Null" value="<%out.print(Memoria.getKernel());%>" />

                        <label title="" class="control-label">Acumulador: </label>
                        <label type="" class="control-label" name="acumulador" ><%out.print(Memoria.getAcumulador());%></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix" ></div>

            <!--fin de superior portatil-->
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">



                    <!--inicio de dropdown vertical-->
                    <div class="btn-group col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

                        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="">
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subir" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Archivo </button>

                                <label type="" class="btn label"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button id="" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> Programas </span> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">

                                    <%
                                        String ruta = "ArchivosCh";
                                        //String ruta = "C:\\Users\\GEORGE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ChMaquina\\web\\ArchivosCh"; funciona perfecto de forma local
                                        File dir = new File(ruta);

                                        String[] nombreArchivos = dir.list();//retorna y guarda la lista de los ficheros en el directorio
                                        int i = 0;
                                        for (String re : nombreArchivos) {//muestra los nombres de los archivos

                                            // out.print("<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle' aria-hidden='true' ><input class='btn btn-default' formaction='LeerArchivo' formtarget='Texto' type='submit' name='cargar' value='" + re + "'/></span><div class='clearfix'></div></li>");
                                    %>
                                    <li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle' aria-hidden='true' ><input class='btn btn-default' formaction='LeerArchivo' formtarget='Pantalla' type='submit' name='cargar' value='<% out.print(re);%> '/></span><div class='clearfix'></div></li>
                                            <%
                                                }
                                            %>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                            <a href="dirMemoria/Memoria.jsp" target="Memoria" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"> Memoria</span></a>
                            <label type="" class="btn label"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></label>
                            <label type="" class="btn label"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></label>

                            <button id="" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" aria-hidden="true"> Inicio <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
                                <li><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="reiniciar" name="reset" formaction="servChMaquina"/></li>
                                <li><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="apagar" name="reset" formaction="servChMaquina"/></li>

                                <%//@include file="dirReset/Reset.jsp" %>    
                            </ul>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <iframe class="" name="Mensajes" width="100%" height="70" frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--fin de dropdown vertial grafica-->
                    <div class="col-lg-11 col-sm-10 col-xs-9">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label class="text">Modo: </label>
                            <label class="badge"><%out.print(Memoria.getModo()); // retorna y muestra el valor de el modo de funcionamiento actual(kernel o usuario) %> </label>

                            <iframe class="" name="Pantalla" width="100%" height="270" frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                    <label class="badge center-block">Variables <a href="dirVariable/Variable.jsp" target="Variable"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a></label>
                                    <iframe class="" name="Variable" width="100%" height="175" frameborder="0" src="dirVariable/Variable.jsp"></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                    <label class="badge center-block">Memoria <a href="dirMemoria/Memoria.jsp" target="Memoria"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a></label>
                                    <iframe class="" name="Memoria" width="100%" height="175" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                    <label class="badge center-block">Etiqueta <a href="dirEtiqueta/Etiqueta.jsp" target="Etiqueta"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a></label>
                                    <iframe class="" name="Etiqueta" width="100%" height="175" frameborder="0" src="dirEtiqueta/Etiqueta.jsp"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <label class="badge center-block">Programa <a href="dirPrograma/Programa.jsp" target="Programa"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a></label>
                                    <iframe class="" name="Programa" width="100%" height="70" frameborder="0" src="dirPrograma/Programa.jsp"></iframe>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </form>

        <!--Modal Instalar-->
        <form class="form-control" name="formAbrir" method="post" action="SubirArchivo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal fade" id="subir" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content ">

                        <div class="modal-header ">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="encenderLabel">Abrir Archivo</h4><div class="spinner-border text-muted"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body ">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div class="form-group ">

                                <div class="">

                                    <div class="form-grup has-default">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="seleccione">Seleccione: <span class="text-muted">Solo archivos de extensión</span> <span class="badge">.ch</span></label>
                                        <input type="file" accept=".ch" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" name="rutaArchivo" /> <br>
                                    </div> 
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="submit" value="Instalar">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true">
                                            Instalar
                                        </span> 
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!--FIN DEL MODAL Instalar -->
    </body>
</html>
```

lo que debe de hacer es entrar a un directorio y buscar todos los archivos que estén allí para enlistarlos en HTML.

el problema es el manejo de las rutas para el hosting. muchas gracias por su ayuda

Imagen del proyecto para ilustar mejor el problema

[image: Proyecto]

Comment: ¿Usas Maven? Simplifica mucho la gestión de estos valores, al permitir tener perfiles diferentes para cada entorno (entorno de producción, pruebas, desarrollo...)

Comment: No, no uso Maven, creo que lo voy a empezar a usar, se nota muy útil la herramienta. muchas gracias

Comment: y el directorio esta dentro o fuera de tu war?

Comment: El directorio esta dentro de la carpeta web del proyecto, es decir dentro del war

Comment: En ese caso si intentas acceder a una carpeta dentro de un war no es posible por ruta,  tienes que obtener cada archivo como un recurso, imagina que el war es como un zip, por lo que no es recomendable trabajar dentro de un war ya que perderías los archivos al eliminar el war o actualizarlo el tomcat.

Comment: pero es posible si 1. Editas el archivo server.xml de tomcat`<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">` para que desempaquete el war al desplegar para que la carpeta tenga una ruta física o 2. Que crees una ruta de volumen nueva en el momento que creas el ambiente al hacer clic en tomcat en la parte inferior clic en volumes -> pestaña volumes -> clic en add y coloca `/local_data` para tener un ruta conocida al desplegar el proyecto sobre la cual trabajar, y cuando inicie tu proyecto copiar los archivos internos a esta ruta y trabajar así el directorio.

Comment: Me ha funcionado obteniendo el archivo como recurso estando en la carpeta web de mi proyecto, sin embargo no he tenido la misma suerte cuando intento hacerlo desde un Servlet ya que la carpeta que contiene los ficheros se encuentra dentro de los archivos web

Comment: Agrego imagen del directorio del proyecto para ilustrar mejor. lo señalado en color ROJO es la carpeta donde están los ficheros a consultar, lo señalado en color AZUL es el archivo que funciona perfecto obteniendo el archivo como recurso, lo señalado en NEGRO es el Servlet desde donde aun no funciona como en el anterior.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que la clase file requiere que el archivo este en una ruta física eso excluye estar dentro de un proyecto.war,   tienes que obtener le recurso como un InputStream para que el archivo exista en memoria y no en una carpeta fisica, `ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
InputStream openStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream( "ArchivoCh/A-Prueba.ch");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream ));`

Comment: gracias @RobertoEMoran por la ayuda aunque solucione el inconveniente, no lo solucione exactamente como la ayuda brindada. pero si fue en base a sus comentarios.

Comment: @PabloLozano ahora utilizo Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de tanto buscar,investigar e intentar todo lo que me decían he dado con una solución. se las presento a continuación.

PARA EL JSP:

```
<%
String ruta = "/ArchivosCh";

File dir = new File(getServletContext().getResource(ruta).getPath());

String[] nombreArchivos = dir.list();//retorna y guarda la lista de los ficheros en el directorio
int i = 0;
for (String re : nombreArchivos) {//muestra los nombres de los archivos


 %>
<li><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle' aria-hidden='true' ><input class='btn btn-default' formaction='LeerArchivo' formtarget='Pantalla' type='submit' name='cargar' value='<% out.print(re);%> '/></span><div class='clearfix'></div></li>
<%
}
%>
```

PARA EL SERVLET:

```
String ruta = "/ArchivosCh/";

//recupera archivos del directorio

            File dir = new File(getServletContext().getResource(ruta).getPath());
//recupera archivos del directorio

            String[] nombreArchivos = dir.list();

            try {

                FileReader archivo = new FileReader(dir.getPath()+"/" + request.getParameter("cargar"));
                BufferedReader filtro = new BufferedReader(archivo);

                String li = filtro.readLine();

                ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

                while (li != null) {
                    lista.add(li);
                    li = filtro.readLine();

                }
                filtro.close();
```

resulta que tenia que crear el objeto file obteniendo el recurso así:

```
File dir = new File(getServletContext().getResource(ruta).getPath());
```

finalmente esto me devolvía una ruta sin el `/`al final, y no podía concatenarse el nombre del archivo y su extensión, así que una vez que la ruta como recurso estaba en el objeto `dir` me dispuse a utilizar sus métodos para obtener el path y concatenarse el símbolo y así completar la ruta perfectamente. `dir.getPath()+"/"`.

muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda. un saludo.