# Problema con servlets de javaweb en heroku

Tags: java, servlets, heroku, war

Estoy probando esta aplicacion simple con heroku, la cual es un registro. Cuando la ejecuto en el servidor de eclipse no tengo ningún problema, realiza el registro correctamente. Sin embargo al desplegarla en heroku y hacer el submit al servlet tengo 2 errores.

**El código del servlet:**

```
    @WebServlet("/Servlet")
    public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
           
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public Servlet() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 

    ServletException, IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
                //Conexion.Conectar();
                boolean crear = create(request.getParameter("correo"),request.getParameter("nombre_usuario"),request.getParameter("pass"));
                //System.out.println(creado);
                
                if(crear){
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("correcto.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    System.out.println("ok");
                }else {
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    System.out.println("mal");
                }
                //System.out.println("ok");
            }
        
            /**
             * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             */
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                doGet(request, response);
            }
            
            
            
            public boolean create(String correo, String nombre_usu, String password) {
                boolean creado = false;
                Connection con = null;
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                try{
                                
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXX");
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (correo,nombre_usuario,clave) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                    System.out.println("Conexion bn");
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.setString(1, correo);
                    ps.setString(2, nombre_usu);
                    ps.setString(3, password);
                    creado = ps.execute;
                
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    try {
                        ps.close();
                        con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return creado;
            }
        }
```

**Los errores**

1)La primera vez que ejecuto la app desplegada al hacer el sumbit me aparece esto:
[image: Primer error]

2. Si hago posteriormente otro submit me da esto:
   [image: Segundo error]

**Mi proyecto**
[image: Proyecto]

[image: Form]

***index.jsp***

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Formulario</h1>
        <form action="Servlet" method="GET">
            Correo <input type="text" name="correo"> <br><br>
            Nombre de usuario <input type="text" name="nombre_usuario"> <br><br>
            Contraseña <input type="text" name="pass"> <br><br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Registrarse">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Por lo que he investigado se podría deber a las rutas como tratan en este post [¿como utilizar las rutas relativas en javaEE para .war en hosting?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320688/como-utilizar-las-rutas-relativas-en-javaee-para-war-en-hosting) sin embargo, he probado pero sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en el primer error, lo mas probable es que esto se deba a una diferencia de las versiones de Java que estas usando localmente comparado con la que estas usando en Heroku al hacer el despliegue de tu aplicacion.

De acuerdo a la imagen de tu proyecto en Eclipse veo que estas usando Java 16. Segun la [documentacion de Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support) ellos usan Java 8 por defecto en caso que no se especifique una versión de Java.

Para especificar la version de Java que quieres usar, segun la documentacion que vinculo arriba, debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Agregar un archivo `system.properties` a tu aplicación
2. En ese archivo agregar una propiedad `java.runtime.version`, en tu caso posiblemente intentar con `java.runtime.version=17` (Java 16 esta marcado como end-of-life y entiendo no te lo va a recibir).

Espero sea de ayuda! Me interesaria saber si esta fue la causa, mi respuesta esta basada en la información que proveiste y no se si haya otra razón detras de escena.

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Si, el error se debía a que estaba usando una versión que Heroku no soporta de Java, por lo que cambie la versión de compilador de mi proyecto en Window -- Preferences -- Java -- Compiler y establecí la 1.8. Con esto ya no tuve ningún problema. Como dices, con system.properties tambien creo que puede funcionar pero no he probado. Por si te puede interesar acerca de este error te dejo esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang- unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi Saludos